# How to convert date and time to specific format in html

Tags: html, angularjs, date

I need to display date and time in specific format inside ng-repeat.

Date value I am getting from backend is "2017-04-03 05:00:07" to "5 hours" if current time is 10am.

If it is a day before means then I need to display yesterday. If it 2 or more days before means i need to display the month like "Apr 03". If it is previous year means i need to display as "01/02/16" (dd/MM/yy).

```
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in messages">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox_square-blue" ng-model="messagesinboxCheck">
    </td>
    <td class="mailbox-name"><a>{{item.from}}</a></td>
    <td class="mailbox-subject">{{item.messagebody.trunc(25)}}
    </td>
    <!--<td class="mailbox-attachment"></td>-->
    <td class="mailbox-type" ng-if="{{item.messagetype}} == 1">SMS</td>
    <td class="mailbox-type" ng-if="{{item.messagetype}} == 0">Email</td>
    <td class="mailbox-type" ng-if="{{item.messagetype}} == 2">SMS & Email</td>
    <td class="mailbox-date">{{item.updateddate}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var messages = {
  "json": {
    "response": {
      "statuscode": "0",
      "statusmessage": "Success",
      "data": {
        "inboxmessages": [{
          "modulereferenceid": 23671,
          "transactionid": 18969,
          "messagebody": "Testing message",
          "messagetype": 1,
          "createddate": "2017-04-03 05:00:07",
          "updateddate": "2017-04-03 05:00:07",
          "forward": false,
          "from": "dinesh",
          "deleted": false,
          "enablecomments": false,
          "url": "/GroupzMobileApp/inbox/avNTaab2hMaaaaeNar6yaaabwMaaanQa"
        }]
      },
      "lastsynchtime": "2017-04-04 06:14:09"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me because I am new to this date functionality.

Comment: Write a filter and convert the date as per your requirement in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="mailbox-date">{{item.updateddate}}</td>
```

use [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

example:  {{ todayDate | date : "dd.MM.yy" }} if todayDate is 04 April 2017 it will show "04.04.17"

Answer (score 0):

we can do this using directives and compare the days and define solution.

So in your HTML part add this directive

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in messages" my-directive="item">
```

Angular Code:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($filter) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        myDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var date1 = new Date(scope.myDirective.updateddate);
        var date2 = new Date();
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        if (diffDays == 1) {
            scope.myDirective.updateddate = 'yesterday'
        } else if (diffDays > 2 && diffDays <= 365) {
            scope.myDirective.updateddate = $filter('date') scope.myDirective.updateddate, 'dd-MMM');
    }
    else if (diffDays > 365) {
        scope.myDirective.updateddate = $filter('date') scope.myDirective.updateddate, 'dd-MM-YYYY');
} } }; });
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: I am getting unexpected identifier at line **"scope.myDirective.updateddate = $filter('date') scope.myDirective.updateddate, 'dd-MMM');"**